# running 2 python windows simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pygame

I'm creating a game app and it has a menu window then a separate game window. I'm trying to get a Tkinter window to act as the menu and a pygame window for the game however if the game is running, I cant use the menu (can't even close it). If I try I get a fatal error message:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00002afc (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Users\James\Documents\6th form\comp sci\NEA- A Level\code\gametst.py", line 12 in main
  File "c:\Users\James\Documents\6th form\comp sci\NEA- A Level\code\Menu.py", line 15 in chess
  File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1421 in mainloop
  File "c:\Users\James\Documents\6th form\comp sci\NEA- A Level\code\Menu.py", line 22 in <module>
```

This is the minimum code to reproduce:

Menu:

```
from tkinter import *
import game

WIN = Tk()
WIN.geometry("200x200")

def f():
    game.main()

button = Button(WIN, text="button", command=f)
button.pack()

WIN.mainloop()
```

game:

```
def main():
    import pygame
    pygame.init()

    WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

    run = 1
    while run:
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = 0
                pygame.quit()
```

Is there a way to do this so that I can use the menu and the game at the same time? thx for any help

also if you know a better way to import the game to the menu that would be great, not overly bothered about that though

Comment: I think you will be much better off if you just try building the whole UI in Pygame.

Comment: Or running the `pygame` part in a separate thread should suffice too

Comment: do you compile the codes? I think if you build both of them as .exe and then run it, it will be okay.

Comment: @James.L if you just run `main()` without anything else does it still produce the problem?

Comment: @TheLizzard If he just runs the `main()` there would be no menu to freeze up, to me it seems that `main()` with its `while` loop is blocking `WIN.mainloop()`, actually it would be rather unseen but he could try using `after()` loops to run pygame, couldn't he?

Comment: @Matiiss even if the `while` loop is blocking `tkinter`, it doesn't explain the error message. That is why I asked if running `main()` without `tkinter` would produce the same error. Also from the traceback I can see that something went wrong in a `c` module (most likely `pygame`) and it was called from `main()`

Comment: @TheLizzard I just run the code and managed to get the same error, but as already the OP mentioned it happens when interacting with menu, to be specific I tried dragging that window. It has certainly to do with the main thread and the fact that there is a loop (could be that since it is related to pygame it threw such an error, nonetheless `main` is blocking the `mainloop` and is certainly a major part of the issue). Also `main()` doesn't have any issues on its own, it just a simple `pygame` window. So my solution would be to use `threading` and put that `pygame` window in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can try to start it in another process. That way `pygame` will have no idea that `tkinter` has started it. You can try something like this:

```py
# menu.py
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import Popen
from sys import stdin, stdout, stderr

window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")

def f():
    proc = Popen("python game.py", stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, shell=True)

button = Button(window, text="button", command=f)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

and:

```py
# game.py
# Please note this isn't in a function.
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

run = True
while run:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
```

The problem is that it isn't going to work if you start it in IDLE. So solve that issue remove the `stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr` and it should work.

With this approach you wouldn't be able to send any data between `menu.py` and `game.py`. The only thing you can do is call `proc_still_alive = (proc.poll() == None)` to see if the process is still alive. For that you will need to make `proc` a global variable.

Comment: Note that `.poll()` returns `None` when the process is still running.  So `has_proc_ended = proc.poll() is not None` should be used instead.

Comment: @acw1668 You are right. Thanks for the suggestion. Next time feel free to edit it :D. I think my brain died

Answer (score 4):

You can run the `pygame` part in a thread:

#### game.py

```py
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()

    WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
    run = 1
    while run:
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = 0
                pygame.quit()
    print("pygame done")

def terminate():
    if pygame.get_init():
        pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(pygame.QUIT))
```

Note that I have added `terminate()` function for stopping the `pygame` loop.

#### menu.py

```py
from tkinter import *
import game

WIN = Tk()
WIN.geometry("200x200")

def f():
    import threading
    # execute the pygame stuff in a thread
    threading.Thread(target=game.main).start()

button = Button(WIN, text="button", command=f)
button.pack()

WIN.mainloop()
game.terminate()  # terminate pygame loop
```

Comment: this is great thanks! but do you know if there is a way to check if the game window s running from the menu? this is because when you press the button while the game is running it stops responding. I tried using the terminate function but it still stops responding.

Comment: never-mind, i used the `is_alive()` function. so thanks for you help